# Convert to long from a given string and return back same string when decoded

Tags: java

I need to convert a string like `"2015114734WO|https://example.com/myresearch/2015114734WO/work/data:/1"` to a long data type and vice versa. It should get converted to a long data type and when algorithm is re-applied, I need to get back `"2015114734WO|https://example.com/myresearch/2015114734WO/work/data:/1"`.
Please let me know if there is any ready algorithm I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: As a primitive form of encryption?

Comment: How do you plan on representing the data uniquely in a long? Bear in mind you only have 8 bytes to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean 'long' as in integral, you could use `BigInteger`. e.g.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

'Decode'

```
            byte[] b = bi.toByteArray();
            for(int i = 0;i < b.length;i++) {  
                System.out.print((char)b[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I convert this back to original string i.e. `"2015114734WO|https://example.com/myresearch/2015114734WO/work/data:/1"`

Comment: Have shown that above. I wonder why you'd do it this way though - it's not compact for one thing